# When to use verb, base verb or gerund

Tags: verbs, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Hello i have question help me please

The children were so frightened they dared not [?].
=> Moving / to move / move ?

Why is the answer "Move" without "to" ?

I have searched and [found a site](https://www.businessenglishresources.com/learn-english-for-business/student-section/student-handouts/infinitive-vs-gerund-combining-two-verbs/) which explain when we use base verb but there is not "dare" in the list.

**Extended question : When to use verb, base verb or gerund ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THERE IS NO GENERAL RULE.

The answer depends on what word governs the clause in question. For example *want* takes an infinitive with "to", *like* takes an infinitive with "to" *or* a gerund.

*Dare* can take an infinitive with or without "to". But it is especially tricky because it is what is sometimes called a *semi-modal*. It can behave as a normal verb (requiring "do"-support for questions and negatives):

> The children were so frightened they didn't dare [to] move.

or, at least for some speakers, as a modal, which doesn't take "do":

> The children were so frightened they dared not move.
>
> Dare you go there?

When it is a modal, it takes only the base form, like other modals.

Speakers vary in how much they use modal *dare*. For example, many people do not use it in the positive, and always use the "to" infinitive then:

> He dared to speak to them

but other speakers do "He dared speak to them".

Some say "dare not" in the present, but would say "didn't dare" in the past.

Comment: *I **dare say** this is correct*. Writing that (as ***two separate*** words), I felt some misgivings, because to me it ***feels*** more like a single-word verb. So I was gratified to find several single-word citations in the full OED under their final definition ***To venture to say** (because one thinks it **likely**); to assume as probable, presume. Almost exclusively in the parenthetic ‘I dare say’; rarely in oblique narration, ‘he dared say’. (In this use now sometimes **written as one word, with stress on the first syllable**.)*

Comment: Thanks you, because the MQC answer was without "to" and so that it meant the with "to" was wrong. How can I know what to do, how to write other verbs please ?

Comment: @TTeaTie: in the example they used _dared not_, so it is a modal, so it cannot take "to". If they had used _didn't dare_ then it could take "to". In answer to your last question: you just have to learn what kinds of complement each verb  takes, in the same way as you have to learn what it means. Sorry.